# PHP JSon How to read boolean value received in JSon format and write in string on PHP

Tags: php, json

I receive this JSON string from another site and I cannot modify what received from.  The string is receive in $_POST and is :

```
[
    {
        "clientId":"17295c59-4373-655a-1141-994aec1779dc",
        "channel":"\/meta\/connect",
        "connectionType":"long-polling",
        "ext":{
            "fm.ack":false,
            "fm.sessionId":"22b0bdcf-4a35-62fc-3764-db4caeece44b"
        },
        "id":"5"
    }
]
```

I decode the JSON string with the following code :

```
$receive = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

And when I use `print_r($receive)` I get the following:

```
Array (
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [clientId] => 17295c59-4373-655a-1141-994aec1779dc
        [channel] => /meta/connect
        [connectionType] => long-polling
        [ext] => stdClass Object
            (
                [fm.ack] => 
                [fm.sessionId] => 22b0bdcf-4a35-62fc-3764-db4caeece44b
            )

        [id] => 5
    )
)
```

I can access and read all Array / Object with no problem :

```
$receive[$i]->clientId;
$receive[$i]->channel;
$connectionType = $receive[$i]->connectionType;
$receive[$i]->id;
$receive[$i]->ext->{'fm.sessionId'};
```

But {fm.ack} is empty

In the decoded JSON string, the false value is not between `""`.

Is it possible to access and read the false value and convert it into string value instead?

Thank you for your helping !

Comment: what is the behaviour if there is `true` in the JSON ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use it like this, in `JSON` format when you evaluate `false` value it will give you `blank`, and when you evaluate `true` it will give you `1`.

```
$str = '[{"clientId":"17295c59-4373-655a-1141-994aec1779dc","channel":"\/meta\/connect","connectionType":"long-polling","ext":{"fm.ack":false,"fm.sessionId":"22b0bdcf-4a35-62fc-3764-db4caeece44b"},"id":"5"}]';

$arr = json_decode($str,true);

if($arr[0]['ext']['fm.ack'])    // suggested by **mario**
{
    echo "true";    
}
else {
    echo "false";   
}
```

Comment: PHP also has a `false`. Why not compare against that? That's what the decoded JSON array contains.

Comment: @mario Yeah we can also comapare with `false`. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar : i try your code from my other question and your code work very well as is, so when i receive the string on $_POST your code dosen't work, only work with : $receive = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); so i try to add ,true after file_get_contents('php://input'), true) and nothing work if i add ,true...

Comment: so if i try :                     if($receive[0]->ext->{'fm.ack'} == "")
                    {
                        echo "false";   
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "true";    
                    } it's work !!! Thank you !

Comment: @LiTHiUM2525 true inside `json_decode` is used for converting all your json data to array format.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yes i know it so is working only if i hardcode my JSon string, not working when i receive JSon string on $_POST the only code can read the string is $receive = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); and not work if i add ,true... so your solution to test if == "" for false else true working well. Thank you

Comment: This is so ghetto.  Running into this problem right now.  In what world should a valid JSON value of "false" be returned as "blank"?

Answer (score 5):

I know there is already an answer to this but it may be worth noting that `var_dump` outputs Boolean values better it just has worse formatting IMO.

```
<pre>
    <?php
        print_r(array(true, false));
        var_dump(array(true, false));
    ?>
</pre>
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 
)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  bool(true)
  [1]=>
  bool(false)
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Booleans were there all along, it's just that print_r() doesn't show them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple. If you use js to generate and transfer json, pass your variable not in its pure form but: `youBoolVar + 0`, then false will be 0, and true 1

Comment: this seems like the simplest answer. worked for me.